# Testing Javascript on Client end

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, node.js, socket.io

I wrote a real time js app that has the following stack:

1. Node.js for server
2. Socket.io as a communication layer
3. JQuery on the front end to manipulate dom etc.

For #1, I have absolutely no problem testing. I am currently using nodeunit which is doing a fantastic job.

For #3, I am having a little trouble trying to figure out my approach to testing.

My browser side code is generally something like that:

```
var user = {
  // Rendered by html
  id: null, 
  roomId: null,
  foo: null, 

  // Set by node server. 
  socket: null,
  clientId: null,
  ... 
}

$('button#ready').click(function() { 
  socket.emit('READY'); 
});

socket.on('INIT', function(clientId, userIds, serverName) { 
  user.clientId = clientId;
  user.foo = (serverName == 'bar') ? 'bar' : 'baz'; 
});
```

The main part which I would like to test involves checking if the js on the browser side will react accordingly when the server fires a certain packet with specified arguments:

i.e.
      **user.foo = (serverName == 'bar') ? 'bar' : 'baz';**

Any good recommendations on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/). It has a very nice support to run both in node and in the browser. I found it vastly more preferable to other options (Jasmine, Vows).

Also, instead of running a heavy-weight integration setup like Selenium, I'm running both server tests and browser tests in one process using [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/). It allows for some beautiful integration workflows (like triggering something on the browser and then verifying effects on the server).

YMMV however as Zombie is relying on JSDOM (DOM re-implementation in Javascript). There are rough edges on yet patched/fixed, stuff breaks. If that's a problem, run Mocha in the browser using real browsers (harnessed through Selenium perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

As much as Pivotal's support for jasmine is a bit hit and miss (minimal new development, lots of unanswered issues/pull-requests on their github), [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/) is a really good tool for testing client-side code, mainly because of [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery).

Jasmine's general approach is pretty solid and Jasmine-Jquery has a lot of great matchers for testing the DOM, as well as great DOM sandboxing.

I found testing on the client-side a challenge, mainly because I had to stop being so rigid and prescriptive in my tests.

Generally, you should approach client-side testing in a kind of 'fuzzy' way, testing the DOM hierarchy too specifically is a road to hell. Test things like, "Does the page contain these words" over "Does div id#my-div contain a ul with 3 li's with content that matches this regex"

The latter is how I started doing tests but I found it incredibly time consuming and fragile; if the designer (me) want to mess with the structure, it'd could unnecessarily break many tests. The only way to get around it is to create 'widgets' for each component, which would be ideal but as I said, very time consuming, it actually became a running joke at my office: "how many tests you done this week Tim? 2? 3? Wow 3 tests. Good work."

Anyway…

You can get 90% of the benefit of doing client-side testing by testing loosely, and focusing on what's important, such as workflow and data 'presence' over specific content in a specific location in the hierarchy on the page.

edit: Also, ensure you break the business logic into units that are independent of the DOM, as much as humanly possible. That makes your life a lot easier, and generally leads to better architecture, which is a plus.

edit 2: You might want to look into how the Rails world does this using Capybara/Cucumber or Selenium.